# Can HTTP proxy modify TCP Java Byte Stream?

Tags: java, http, tcp, proxy, packet

I am sending Bytes via TCP with Java via Socket connected to HTTP proxy, is it possible that the HTTP proxy is changing the order or adding some header to the bytes sent ?

Because sometimes the packet that arrives to the server is malformed but I am 100% sure that the packet is sent from client in correct format, also this never happens when I send packet without proxy.

How can I be sure that the proxy does not change the order of bytes or it does not add something to the packet ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It is also possible that your code does not handle proxies correctly.  Show minimal code having the problem.

Comment: It's possible, simplest solution would be to use send data over SSL

Comment: @11thdimension But to use the SSL the Proxy Server has to support SSL right ?

Comment: Yes, it would be required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible that a http proxy is changing your data while in transit.

Encrypt the data to prevent that, you can exchange encryption keys with say the Diffie-Hellman protocol.

Comment: Well, but I can access only client code not the server one so I dont think so I could use this protocol.